# How to handle "inquiry age" as a variable in a regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification, multiple-regression

I am trying to create a logistic regression model that will allow me to give weights to several categorical variables related to inquiries about sales of high value products. An example of the same vein would be vacation rentals, predicting whether or not there will be a purchase so that the inquiries can be ranked for order of "follow up calls" to try and close the sale. Let's say in the rental example, the variables are room type (queen, king, suite), inquiry source (phone, web, or app), customer status (new vs repeat buyer), and, the potentially most useful, age of inquiry in days. 80% sales are made within 3 days of the inquiry, so we obviously want to weight inquiries before this time more heavily, but I want to put this into the regression to get a real weight when others are held constant.

I originally just assumed in my training data I could use "days to buy" as a placeholder, as 0,1,2,3, and 4+ (or no buy). Quickly realized this doesn't make sense because it's not the same as the age of new incoming inquiries, so the weights would just tell you the log odds of a purchase ON THAT DAY, not the total potential for purchase as the inquiry ages. Is there any good way to handle this? I am using glm() in R. I am also open to other model types and methods, but it doesn't need to be fancy, just defensible.

Edit: many people suggest survival analysis which I was reading up on yesterday but I'm confused as to whether I could solve the above problem in its entirety that way, as time to buy would be an output not an input? Any specifics would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, then one way to approach this would be survival analysis, aka time to event analysis.

I wouldn't use ChatGPT for statistical analysis. I would use CrossValidated. :-).

Comment: Have you considered using survival analysis model instead?

Comment: Ordinal info (0,1,2,3,4+) isn't as informative or useful as the # of days since last inquiry which can be calculated as (today's data - date of last inquiry).

Comment: Thanks all for the answers- I had come across survival analysis but struggling to understand how it would specifically help me with the weights, if anyone could be more detailed it'd be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how survival analysis would aid, using your example, ranking new customers for a follow up call. You've got a logistic regression model built on known purchasers using several features, correct? And you've validated it based on train-test sampling. Essentially, this is a direct marketing response model with new customers having an unknown probability of purchase (response) but a complete set of information wrt the predictive features. Next, score new customers using this model and, in a DM world, create deciles wrt likelihood of purchase. Call the customers in the top deciles.

Comment: @MikeHunter thank you, that makes a lot of sense, I'll try that. I may have to come back to the forum with related questions when I get stuck again :)